# erlang zip:unzip/1 {error, bad_central_directory} and {error, bad_eocd}

Tags: linux, unix, erlang, zip, gzip

I have always used erlang `stdlib` library `zip:unzip/1` successfully. Last night i hit a bar with this error:

```
E:\WimaxStatsParser-1.1>erl
Eshell V5.9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> zip:unzip("e:/WimaxStatsParser-1.1/in/SomeZipFile.zip").
{error,bad_central_directory}
2>
```

Some one help explain the cause for this ? and how i get around it ?

**ADDITIONS**

---

I got some other error on another file:  `{error,bad_eocd}`. Please explain this as well.

Comment: It had happened to me before that certain zip files can't be unzipped by Erlangs zip module.  It depends on how your zip file was created.  But it might be something different but since there is no real standard for zip files all kinds of variants are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce your problem with the information you give. There are 2 functions that may send this error:

get_cd_loop/5 and get_name_extra_comment/4 in stdlib-1.18.2/src/zip.erl .

it should be easy to debug

copy the file zip.erl, zip.hrl, file.hrl in a working directory,

compile with debug_info option, you will get the error message "Can't load module that resides in sticky dir", leave the VM

copy zip.beam in the stdlib.../ebin

restart the VM in the working directory, you can now add breakpoint in the zip.erl source.

BR

Pascal.

Comment: Before messing up your Erlang distribution you should rather start your VM with -nostick then it won't complain.  Also I'd recommend dbg tracing over single stepping in the debugger

Comment: Alternatively you could call code:unstick_dir(Dir) on a single directory if you need to override the stickyness from your code. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html for details

Comment: I didn't know this option. I will have a look to understand how it works. On my side I use to keep the official beam and restore it as soon as I have finished, not elegant but very simple knowing that my PC is not a production machine.

Comment: True, the zip files were corrupted. When i tried with a different `un-zipper`, it threw exceptions as well.