# Unzipping files with Elixir throws :data_error

Tags: elixir

I'm downloading a file from Google Cloud Storage (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get#parameters)

The binary contents of the file are returned on the response body. Using :zlib.uncompress throws me

```
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :data_error
```

I've checked the contents of the file by saving it on disk and extracting manually.

Is there another way to unzip a file in elixir/erlang without using unix commands?

Edit:

Inspecting the binaries gave me an ok

```
r.body |> inspect(binaries: :as_binaries) |> IO.puts
<<31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 212, 253, 91, 115, 27, 73, 178, 53, 10, 190, 207, 175, 104, 219, 207, 95, 193, 50, 174, 153, 57, 111, 188, 64, 36, 27, 44, 146, 6, 146, 170, 22, 95, 218, 212, 85, 234, 106, 157, 93, ...>>
:ok
```

Comment: can you try `:zip.uncompress(zipped_file)`

Comment: @coderVishal Got `undefined function`. Do you have the docs for that module?

Comment: Can you post a link to an example file so we can try decompressing ourselves? If it's short, just include the output of this in the question: `File.read("the_file") |> inspect(binaries: :as_binaries) |> IO.puts`.

Comment: @paulorcdiniz sorry, please do `inspect(limit: :infinity)` instead. The default output truncates to 100 or so bytes. (`:ok` is just the return value of successfully printing using `IO.puts`.)

Comment: @Dogbert Just did, it printed the entire binary file on my console. Does that mean it's not corrupted?

Comment: @paulorcdiniz no, please include the output in the question or upload to gist.github.com and post a link in the question if it's too long (> 5kb let's say). Then I'll be able to see if it's actually corrupted or not locally and try to find out why it's not unzipping using the `zip` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Reading from an erlang forum (http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-November/047832.html) I found out the correct steps:

```
z = :zlib.open
:zlib.inflateInit(z, 31)
:zlib.inflate(z, result.body)
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Quick question: Does `:zlib.gunzip(result.body)` work?

Comment: @Dogbert Weird, `:zlib.gunzip` never returns. It strands

Comment: That's strange, and probably a bug - it should either return the uncompressed data or throw an error, never hang.

Comment: @Dogbert Will let it run again for a couple of hours. Will post the response here. Thanks!

Comment: You mean let `:zlib.gunzip` run? It shouldn't be that slow, I believe it should run at least a few megabytes per second. If the data is not sensitive, would you mind uploading it somewhere and posting a link? (You can do `File.write!("a", result.body)` and upload `a` to Dropbox or Google Drive or anything.)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [zip](http://erlang.org/doc/man/zip.html) from erlang. The function you are looking for is `unzip`

```
:zip.unzip(zipped_file)
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't quite work, but now the error is MUCH more explicit: `{:error, :bad_eocd}`

Comment: maybe this will help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908409/erlang-zipunzip-1-error-bad-central-directory-and-error-bad-eocd